# Unexpected code point conversion

Tags: go, unicode

Why is one byte converted to rune with value 65533 instead of 132 in the following application?

I have ascii code conversion table (old ascii code -> new ascii code) that I should implement, so I need the correct **ascii** values (132 in this case) in converter.

Sample program:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "flag"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func converter(r rune) rune {
    fmt.Printf("%v ", int(r))
    return r
}

func main() {

    // parse the command line
    var infile string
    flag.StringVar(&infile, "in", "", "input file")
    flag.Parse()

    // read the whole file at once
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(infile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", b)

    // convert charset
    converted := bytes.Map(converter, b)

    fmt.Printf("\n%v\n", converted)
}
```

Sample input file (in hex):

```
4A 84 6C 6B 0D 0A
```

Sample output from the application:

```
[74 132 108 107 13 10]
74 65533 108 107 13 10
[74 239 191 189 108 107 13 10]
```

Comment: If you look up the documentation what bytes.Map does you will see that why your code is broken. If your input is not UTF-8 encoded, than interpreting it as UTF-8 will produce garbage. BTW What is "old ascii" and/or "new ascii". Can you describe the actual problem?

Comment: 132 is not an ascii value.

Comment: Please consider using the battle-tested [`golang.org/x/text/encoding`](http://golang.org/x/text/encoding) package instead of reinventing the wheel: conversions between various character sets is a very difficult task (as is text processing in general).
As an added bonus, this package provides for *stream* conversion—that is, it makes it possible to convert text piecemeal—by wrapping an `io.Reader` producing the source text into another one, producing the converted text.

Comment: @Volker I am working with a custom encoding that is application specific. It is not any of the well known sets, so I really do need a weird custom translation table. Thank you for your comments in anyways, the couple provided answers verified what I suspected already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rune is a Unicode value, not ASCII. So your bytes are interpreted as UTF8.

If we look at the function that you are using:
https://golang.org/src/bytes/bytes.go?s=9029:9081#L344

We can see that for every byte in slice it is converted to Unicode rune.

```
r := rune(s[i])
```

What it does is a conversion of bytes, starting from s[i] to UTF8 letter.

**In UTF8 one letter can
occupy more that one byte**. This is opposite to ASCII encoding where
one letter always takes one byte.

You can read more about UTF8 here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

This is the reason you have the wrong result.

To fix it, you should iterate over your bytes using for range loop and save the output to new slice.

```
func converter(b byte) byte {
    fmt.Printf("%v ", int(r))
    return b
}

...

converted := make([]byte, len(b))

for i, v := range b {
   // v is your byte value - convert it here
   converted[i] = converter(v)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the bytes from the text, and then you can use something on these lines - the last column in the output will be comparable to the ASCII value.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    //s := "Hello, 世界"
    //Assuming the following is the hex you have read in from the file..
    b, err := hex.DecodeString("48656c6c6f2c20e4b896e7958c")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(b)
    s := string(b)
    for i := 0; i < len(s); {
        r, size := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s[i:])
        fmt.Printf("%d\t%c\t%d\n", i, r, r)
        i += size
    }
    anotherWay(s)

}
func anotherWay(s string) {
    fmt.Println("\nAnother way")
    for i, r := range s {
        fmt.Printf("%d\t%c\t%d\n", i, r, r)
    }
}
```

On playground : https://play.golang.org/p/9WusGxWv8w